# Dual Boot Z97-A Motherboard

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-10

I'm trying to create a dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I have 4 hard drives. Windows 10 is installed in an SSD and allocated two hard drives for personal information and games. In the fourth hard drive I have installed Ubuntu 18.04. At the moment everything is working fine.

**I would like to have a boot menu and choose the OS when I turn on my computer.**

At the moment I have to get into the BIOS and change the boot priority in order to start Ubuntu or Windows 10.

My motherboard is an Asus Z97-A.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode? And when you boot Ubuntu does not grub also show Windows? I have Asus Z97-ar which is the same system. My system has multiple drives & multiple Ubuntu installs, but no Windows. Up until a few days ago, it worked fine. But then and efibootmgr error said no room in UEFI. I now can only boot with rEFInd. I think I have changed some setting & need to change it back. Post link to summary report above. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Mine for ref: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9HWjPVdHkc/

Comment: Honestly I don't know if both OS are in UEFI boot mode. I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu is, can't remember if windows is too.

Grub doesn't show anything when I boot under Ubuntu.

Comment: It may not be then. Report will show details. UEFI & BIOS boot are not compatible. System writes data differently for operating system to use. So grub can only boot other systems in same boot mode. If Windows drive is MBR, then BIOS, or if gpt then UEFI as it requires those partition configurations for each type of boot.

Comment: I'm doing my best to understand what you just wrote. What would be the solution? Reinstall windows and select UEFI boot mode? 

I have the pendrive with windows inside, the one i used to install my current Windows version. Is there any way to check in which mode did i create the bootable pendrive? I used Rufus btw, all with the defaults options, for both, Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: That is why I asked for the Summary Report. It shows all the details. How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS from UEFI boot menu, is then how it installs for both Ubuntu & Windows.

Comment: I'll try to provide a summary report after work. Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved. Ubuntu wasn't installed under uefi mode. Thanks everybdy